# Would these function variables hold their value when the function has ended?

Tags: c, function

I am little confused on how I can make a variable within a function hold its value so that the next time I call the function again it still holds the same value as the last time the function was run. I know I can pass variables into functions etx. But im specifically looking for a way to create a variable within the function itself and make it hold it value.

I would like to store:

```
int count = 0;
```

Could this be done somehow using pointers?

Comment: for your purpose, I can use either static or a global variable (outside your function) which you modify inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called [`static`](http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.6.html) variables.

```
void Func()
{
    static int count =0;
    count++;
}
```

Here is a sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int * Func()
{
    static int count =-1;
    count++;
    return &count;
}
int main(void) {

    printf("%d\n", *Func());
    printf("%d\n", *Func());
    printf("%d\n", *Func());
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `static` storage class specifier, this would work as you want

```
void
function(void)
{
    static int count; // Implicitly initialized to `0'
    printf("called `%d' times", ++count);
}
```

In the context of a function the `static` keyword makes the variable preserve it's value across function calls. Some library functions are implemented with `static` variables but there is a problem with this.

A function with a static variable is not in theory *reentrant*. If you use the function for different purposes or in different threads the value will be preserved anyway and you might not want that, an example of a function with this behavior is `strtok()` if you use it to tokenize 2 strings it doesn't work as you'd expect.

To solve this there is a `strtok_r()` POSIX function that takes a third parameter to do what the internal `static` pointer does, it keeps *context* across function calls for a given string that is being tokenized.

As an example, check this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void
function(void)
{
    static int variable;
    printf("thread: `0x%lX' -- value: `%d'\n", pthread_self(), ++variable);
    sleep(1);
}

void *
call_the_function(void *data)
{
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
        function();
    return NULL;
}

int
main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, call_the_function, NULL);
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
        function();
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

You will see that no matter which thread calls `function()` the value of `variable` is preserved and is incremented on every call to `function()`.